# SAS assigning numbers and partitioning by account

Tags: sas, sas-macro, enterprise-guide

I use SAS EG and have a data set that looks like:

```
CLIENT_ID    Segment     Yearmonth
XXXX         A            201305
XXXX         A            201306
XXXX         A            201307
YYYY         A            201305
YYYY         A            201306
YYYY         B            201307
```

i want an output that has a number assigned to a new column which resets when a new account is there:

```
CLIENT_ID    Segment      Yearmonth    New_Variable    
XXXX         A            201305         1
XXXX         A            201306         2
XXXX         A            201307         3
YYYY         A            201305         1
YYYY         A            201306         2
YYYY         B            201307         3
```

That was problem number one, which i solved with this code:

```
PROC SORT DATA= GENERAL.HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS;
by Client_ID;
RUN;

data HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS2;
SET GENERAL.HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS;
count + 1;
by Client_ID;
if first.Client_ID then count = 1;
run;
```

I want to create a second data set and  i want to see if there is a way to get the segments only if the segment changes: For example from the above the

```
CLIENT_ID    Segment      Yearmonth    New_Variable
YYYY         A            201305         1
YYYY         B            201306         2
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please add what code you have tried to the question (even if it didn't work).  Seeing how you approached it often helps others help your learning, rather than just giving you an answer.  Are you familiar with RETAIN, and by group processing in a DATA step (e.g. first.Account and last.Account)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice job on answering your first question.  I think that step reads more clearly if you rearrange it a bit, e.g.:

```
data HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS2 ;
  set GENERAL.HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS ;
  by Client_ID ;
  if first.Client_ID then count = 0 ;
  count + 1 ;
run;
```

I think it's customary to put the BY statement right after the SET statement it applies to, for clarity sake.  Reset the counter to 0 when Client_ID changes.

It looks like you want a second dataset, call it FIRSTS, with the first record from each by group.  To do that, note that it's possible for one DATA step to write multiple output datasets.  This can be done by using an explicit OUTPUT statement to write to each dataset, e.g. :

```
data HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS2 FIRSTS ;
  set GENERAL.HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS ;
  by Client_ID ;
  if first.Client_ID then count = 0 ;
  count + 1 ;
  output HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS2 ; *output every record;
  if first.Client_ID then output FIRSTS ;  *output first of each group;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer. That makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: still struggling with getting this logic in there:    HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS2 FIRSTS ;                                               
    set GENERAL.HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS ;
    by Client_ID ;
    if first.Client_ID then count = 0 ;
    count + 1 ;
      output HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS2 ; *output every record;
      if first.Client_ID then output FIRSTS ;  *output first of each group;
      if  second.segment <> first.segment then output FIRSTS
run;
basically I want a logic where it would output to the table first the client id only if the segment is different than the previous segment

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding. Suggest you either add this to the current question, or maybe better, start a new question with a few more example records to show the records you would like to output with this new logic.